# How can I prevent error when subdomain does not exist?

Tags: nginx, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

Every subdomain is in a separate folder. I capture the subdomain and set the root to the correct folder with this code:

```
server_name ~^(?<sub>.+)\.mysite\.com$;
root "/path/to/my/site/$sub";
```

When the sub domain does not exist, it throws a 404 error, but not using my 404 error page because the root is set to a directory that does not exist.

I can solve the problem with this code:

```
server_name ~^(?<sub>.+)\.mysite\.com$;
if (!-d "/path/to/my/site/$sub") {
    set $sub www;
    #set $sub "";
}
root "/path/to/my/site/$sub";
```

but obviously, it is wrong because [if is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/), or have I found an exception where it is correct of me to use `if`.

Comment: Why do you need to do it in the same `server` block? Use a catch-all `server` block. See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/783346/prevent-default-server-or-wildcard-in-nginx/783375#783375), but make the response anything you like.

Comment: Why not use an `error_page`?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have tried with `error_page` and it doesn't work. It only works if the error page is static, and it needs to be a `.php` file.

Comment: But, a PHP file from which document root?

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with the code for my error page. That now works, which has allowed me to fix a different problem (extensionless php with redirects).

```
error_page 404 =200 /404.php;    
location = /404 {
    #root "/path/to/404/page";
}
```

I tried setting the root inside `location = /404` but that does not work. I have found no way to avoid the `if` statement and still make it work correctly.

```
if (!-d "/path/to/my/site/$sub") {
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

I guess it's better to have a very small amount of `if` statements for redirects, than to have a broken website.

Even Plesk Onyx's auto generated code used an `if` statement:

```
if ($host ~* ^example\.com$) {
    return 301 https://www.$host$request_uri;
}
```

However, I would still prefer to avoid `if` statements altogether, if i can get my site to work 100% correctly without them.