# nginx to handle odd requests on hostname

Tags: nginx

Application logs are showing requests for a domain which is in fact the ip address of the server

```
host = 'www.166.77.88.99'
```

Thus I created an additional enabled site as follows:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443;
  server_name 166.77.88.99 www.166.77.88.99;
  location ~ / {
      return 404;
  }
}
```

This does process requests for the ip address to the 404 response. However, there is no way to test the second hostname; any local machine returns

```
curl http://www.166.77.88.99/
Could not resolve host: www.166.77.88.99
```

I fail to comprehend how is traffic even being generated to the ipaddress in this manner?
How can this be denied by nginx?

Comment: Use: `curl -H "Host: www.166.77.88.99" http://166.77.88.99/` - but it would be better to define a catch-all server block to reject any invalid server name rather than providing an exhaustive list of invalid server names. See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/783346/prevent-default-server-or-wildcard-in-nginx/783375#783375). And you are missing the `ssl` attribute from the `listen 443 ssl;` statement.

Comment: yes, that attribute was missing.  The suggested link is appropriate and resolves the issue well.

Comment: The `location` is unnecessary and of course will have a performance penalty from using the also unnecessary regex. You can just `return 404;` and be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can just set the `Host` header and use something like curl to send the request to the IP address.

e.g.

```
curl -H 'Host: www.166.77.88.99' http://166.77.88.99
```